# Can Harlowe for Twine 2 handle variable references inside a Datamap?

Tags: twine, harlowe

I'm starting to learn Twine and I'm putting together a little framework for making a game.

I'm trying to make a DataMap named 'Door' that has a key/value pair of "openCondition",$doorUnlocked. What currently happens is that "openCondition" is set to what $doorUnlocked is when 'Door' is created (false).  This is fine, but when $doorUnlocked becomes 'true', "openCondition" stays the same, because it's already been set.

Is is possible to set a DataMap value to a reference of a variable?
Are reference variables even built into Harlowe?
If not, are they available in any other Twine format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not really.** Harlowe offers a very simplified interface to JavaScript and does some stuff to shield inexperienced developers from potential "gotchas" like accidentally constructing a reference. Looking at the Harlowe source, DataMaps are implemented using JavaScript Maps, and whenever a value is set on them, it seems to `clone()` the value before assigning it.

Depending on your level of comfort with JS, you may find more success with the Snowman 2 format, which is basically Underscore templating. You'd be able to use one of the JS techniques to simulate reference values: probably either passing around objects or using closures.

A workaround is to always store the door-is-unlocked value in one place: either in `$Door's opencondition` or in `$doorUnlocked` but not in both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I sort of suspected this but it's good to get a confirmation. I'll probably do as you suggest and keep the condition in the Door, until I'm comfortable enough for a different format. Also thank you for creating the twine tag, hopefully that will encourage more questions.