# Creating a lookup table of datamaps in Harlowe/Twine

Tags: twine, harlowe

I'm attempting to procedurally-generate a list of linked `Passages` in Harlowe 3 and am running into that [lovely wall of simplified programming that is presented to the developer.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141448/can-harlowe-for-twine-2-handle-variable-references-inside-a-datamap)  The thing is that I just want to prototype a simple story without converting everything over to Sugarcube/Snowman.

What I am trying to do and am struggling with is figuring out how to generate an `Array` of `Passages` and link them together.  I am absolutely OK with creating temporary lookup tables to link things together, however I'm struggling with the syntax for it.

My current feeling is that something like this *should* work, but I can't wrap my head around the API reference for this kind of activity.  The following is a pseudo-code attempt at what I'm trying to accomplish ... it doesn't work straight up but is an amalgamation of what I've been trying.

```
(set: $rooms to (a:))
(set: $num_rooms to range(1,20))
(for: each _iter, $num_rooms)[
  (set: $rooms to $rooms + (a: (dm: "title", "Room " + _iter, "Description", "Room " + _iter + " Description"))))
]

(set: $lookup to (dm:))
(for: each $room, $rooms):
  (for: each $room2, $rooms)):
    (if: $room is not $room2):
      <!-- random chance that it links up, example here to set the 'left' passage -->
      (set: $lookup to $lookup + (dm: "Room1_Left", $room2))
```

Then later on, pull up:

`[[Go left | $lookup->Room1_Left]]`

The issue is that I am struggling with some of the syntax here.  The above code doesn't work for me and I'm struggling with coercing it into the 'ideal' format.

If this is completely **infeasible** then that is fine, but I'm fairly certain I can hack this in with the correct syntax.  (Future projects I'd switch over to Sugarcube, but I want to try and give this the old college try before I completely dump it and refactor).

**Edit**

I got frustrated and switched over to Sugarcube (and 15 minutes into reading documentation/examples I'm already beyond where I got with Harlowe).  HOWEVER I'm going to leave this question up for now as I can see it being exceedingly valid for non-programmers to extend their IF games.  If a good answer rolls along I'll try it out in my local project.